# How to decide whether the noun after "other" is singular or plural?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I checked these two sentences in the grammar checker. The grammar checker suggested "type" and "animal" in the first sentence need to be in singular form. However, in the second sentence, "type" and "animal" need to be in plural form. Why?

1. He bought a cat, dog, or other type of animal.
2. He bought a cat, a dog, and other types of animals.

Additional question.

1. He bought a cat, dog, or other type of animal.
2. He bought a cat, a dog, or another type of animal.

Is there any differences in the meaning between these two sentences?

Thank you in advance

Comment: In the context of that sentence, it's not clear how many animals "other type of animal" refers to. Your grammar checker is making its *best guess*, but since it doesn't know, it could be wrong. I can't tell what the intended meaning is, so I can't say which is correct or why.

Answer (score 0):

In 1 it sounds as if he only bought one animal - i.e a cat, or a dog, or somethinmg else. The reporter is clearly not sure what animal he actually bought.

If I were speaking I would most likely say "...a cat, dog, or some other (type of) animal".

In 2 it sounds as though he bought several animals. But it is a bit clunky the way it is written. Were I reporting it I might say- "He bought, a cat, a dog, and some other animals - of various types".

Answer (score 0):

In this context, "other types" can only mean more than one.

If he bought just three animals, it would say:

> He bought a dog, a cat, and another type of animal.